# Installing application and requires python-tornado 2.2.0

Tags: linux, tornado, centos6

I'm trying to install an rpm package.

> It keeps saying Requires: python-tornado >= 2.2.0

I have installed tornado 3.2 but the problem still exist.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`python-tornado`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-tornado) is the correct RPM for the tornado web framework written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install tornado 3.2 with pip or with an rpm?  RPM doesn't know about things installed with pip, so you'll need an RPM version of tornado to use with this rpm (or install whatever you're trying to install here with pip instead of rpm)